# I cant find my service Path in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, path

i am searching for this path for hours now and hope you could help me. 
I created a service and want to access it from my components.

My files are organized like that:

[image: My files are organized like that:]

I want to import "shared.service.ts" to "main-quiz.component.ts.

I already tried

```
import { SharedService } from './shared,service';
import { SharedService } from '././shared,service';
import { SharedService } from 'src/app/shared.service';
```

I really dont know why that is not working...
Please help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { SharedService } from '../shared.service';
```

where  .. is parent directory

Answer (score 1):

```
import { SharedService} from '../shared.service;
```

Which means "I want to find the file from the directory above"

Likewise , if it was two directories above , you'd do something like: '../../filename'

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
import { SharedService } from '../shared,service';
```